# the first while loop iterates, but does not change the value inside of the second loop

Tags: python

I am trying to use a nested loop in order to delete certain lines from a .tsv file that i have. The lines that i want to delete all start with MD# and i am trying to iterate the number using a while loop.

The first time that the number is used 'MD1' all 10 of the lines that contain that as the first string on the line are removed, however afterwards MD2, MD3, etc are not.

As I am still a bit rusty with Python I had set up a very crude if statement in order to remove the lines, this worked although it is not the prettiest code in the world.

included is an example of what the data looks like, 4 columns wide, 320 rows

```
[['MD1', 'Liverpool', 'Draw', 'Norwich'],
 ['Google', '0.85', '0.10', '0.05'],
 ['Bookies', '0.14', '7.00', '25.00'],
 ['Outcome', '11.43', '80.00', '260.00'],
 ['MD1', 'West Ham', 'Draw', 'Man. City'],
 ['Google', '0.09', '0.17', '0.74'],
 ['Bookies', '12.00', '5.00', '0.25'],
 ['Outcome', '130.00', '60.00', '12.50'],
 ['MD1', 'Crystal Palace', 'Draw', 'Everton'],
 ['Google', '0.30', '0.30', '0.40'],
 ['Bookies', '2.10', '2.20', '1.38'],
 ['Outcome', '31.00', '32.00', '23.75'],
 ['MD1', 'Burnley', 'Draw', 'Southhampton'],
 ['Google', '0.35', '0.31', '0.34'],
 ['Bookies', '1.63', '2.20', '1.75'],
 ['Outcome', '26.25', '32.00', '27.50'],
```

```py
import csv
import numpy as np

data_list = []
with open('Sheet7.tsv',newline = '') as data:
    data_reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter = '\t')
    for data in data_reader:
        data_list.append((data))
datamod = np.array([])
datamod = data_list

games = 8
i = 0
g = 1

while g <= games:
    MDg = ('MD'+str(g))
    g +=1
    while i < len(datamod):

        if datamod[i][0] == MDg:
            datamod = np.delete(datamod, i, axis = 0)
            i +=1

        else:
            i +=1
```

alternative code used

```py
while i < len(datamod):
    if datamod[i][0] == 'MD1':
        datamod = np.delete(datamod, i, axis = 0)
    if datamod[i][0] == 'MD2':
        datamod = np.delete(datamod, i, axis = 0)
    if datamod[i][0] == 'MD3':
        datamod = np.delete(datamod, i, axis = 0)
    if datamod[i][0] == 'MD4':
        datamod = np.delete(datamod, i, axis = 0)
    if datamod[i][0] == 'MD5':
        datamod = np.delete(datamod, i, axis = 0)
    if datamod[i][0] == 'MD6':
        datamod = np.delete(datamod, i, axis = 0)
    if datamod[i][0] == 'MD7':
        datamod = np.delete(datamod, i, axis = 0)
    if datamod[i][0] == 'MD8':
        datamod = np.delete(datamod, i, axis = 0)
    i += 1
```

so i would expect the result to not have every 4th line and therefore be a list with 240 rows instead of the original 320

if anyone could help me with this it would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Seem like one issue is that the `i` variable is not getting reset to `0` after a complete iteration of the outer loop. You should reset the `i` value in the outer loop. Better yet, consider changing both `while` loops to `for` loops using the `for i in range(length):` construction of iteration. Hope this helps! https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-range-function/

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
You didn't bother to trace your execution; `print(g, MDg, i)` would have saved you the trouble of posting.

Comment: Imo this is _far_ too complicated. Why don't you simply check already at import loop if a line starts with 'MD' and skip its import depending on this check?

Comment: Next: sth like `datamod = np.array([]); datamod = data_list` is completely futile. In python you don't declare variable types like you wanted to do here. In this code, `datamod` was an empty numpy array for one line to be immediately overwritten by a list. The reason why it later works in your numpy functions is, that numpy silently casts lists to numpy arrays on its own on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like one issue is that the `i` variable is not getting reset to `0` after a complete iteration of the outer `while` loop. You should reset the `i` value in the outer loop.

Better yet, consider changing both `while` loops to `for` loops using the `for i in range(length):` construction of iteration.

Hope this helps!

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-range-function/

Comment: Ah, yep that worked perfectly!
thank you for the help on such a trivial problem, just not written code in many moons haha

Comment: Good to hear. If you will be working further with parsing text and other character based data, take a look at learning about regular expressions, as shown in the other answer. It's a very powerful and flexible tool in finding what you are looking for in text smarter, faster, and with less code. These are a good reference and start, respectively. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Answer (score 2):

There's too much replication and it can be further generalized. If you do not need the trailing digit after `MD` for any comparison, just omit the lines that look like that right away.

The following code loads all data into a list and at the same time checks whether the first data field matches `^MD\d+$`, which means *starts with `MD` followed by one or more digits without any additional trailing character*:

```
import csv
import re

with open('Sheet7.tsv', newline='') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    data = [
        line for line in reader
        if not re.match('^MD\d+$', line[0].strip())
    ]
```

Your resulting list is then stored in the `data` variable and should be ready for further calculations.

Comment: Yes, agree this is much better than the direction of the original code.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd do sth like

```
data_list = []
with open('Sheet7.tsv') as f:
    for line in f:
        cols = line.split('\t')
        if cols[0].startswith('MD') and cols[0][2:].isdigit():
            data_list.append(cols)
```